# Can you see a history of games from your Steam discovery queue?

Tags: steam

I had gone through several days worth of discovery queues during this sale, adding things to my cart.  Then, one day my cart was empty, and I lost everything I'd been saving up there.

[This reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/Steam/comments/3y2g8p/psa_heres_how_to_see_the_titles_you_marked_as_not/) explains how to see games which you've marked as "Not Interested", but I'm looking for games I was interested in enough to put in my cart (and thus didn't bother wishlisting).  Is there any way to see this history?  Or is it gone for good?

Comment: On a side note, this is why it's a good idea to save things to your wishlist instead.

Comment: ^^^This, and it saves you a ton of money when you go back through your wishlist a week later and say "what was I thinking with *this one*?!"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check your *Discovery Queue History* at your [GDPR webpage](https://help.steampowered.com/en/accountdata/DiscoveryQueueHistory).

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Ooooh, that's it.  And it even goes back to last year, if I really want to make the effort to try and find those games again.